# Nginx doesn't send _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] to PHP-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

This is part of my nginx configuration file:

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Almost the website loads because the location of / is also set to /var/www on this config file.

```
location / {
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

When I use phpinfo() and read PHP variables table, I noticed this:

```
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Other variables (most of them configured in nginx.conf)as server name, script filename, etc, were sent to php. So, nginx doesn't sending this variable to PHP.
What I have to do?

I'm using PHP 5.3.8 and nginx 0.8

Comment: Move your 'root' directive outside the location blocks - it should be in the server block (and verify that you have a line reading `fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;` in your fastcgi_parms file)

Comment: It's already inside in the Default Server Block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$document_root is set by the root directive.  The 'root html;' line in the php location sets $document_root to <nginx prefix>/html.  Take a look at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block to see how you should be setting your root in the server context.  It should look something like this:

```
server {
  root /var/www;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using nginx 1.0.6, and this is in my fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
```

Not sure if this will help you on 0.8, but updating nginx will help if not.

Comment: Not really, it's the same in nginx 0.8

Comment: @ianenri: It works perfectly on 1.0. Could be a bug in 0.8 then. Still, this is how you set it. You could set it manually rather than via the variable, that should solve your issue.

Comment: And where I should set this $document_root variable?

Comment: @ianenri: I'd add a line to your `location`, directly after the `include fastcgi_params` that is something like `fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /var/www;`. I doubt you can actually set `$document_root`. Also, look at kolbyjacks answer, as that's likely the root of the problem.